# como atribuir codigo html na variavel javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

quero atribuir esse codigo

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
```

a uma variavel JS, tipo isso :

```
var Code = '<div class="menu">...</div>
```

Comment: quero atribuir um codigo hmtl dentro de uma variaavel pra, que eu faça imprimir depois,  apenas // document.write(varialvelHtml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se tiver apenas um elemento com a `class` na página, você pode fazer assim:

```
var Code = document.body.querySelector(".menu");
```

Se forem mais, você deverá especificar um índice, com `querySelectorAll`:

```
var Code = document.body.querySelectorAll(".menu")[1];
```

O onde o `[1]` representa o segundo elemento da página com a classe `.menu`.

---

Os exemplos acima irão selecionar o elemento como um objeto. Se quiser pegar o HTML, adicione `.outerHTML`:

```
var Code = document.body.querySelector(".menu").outerHTML;
```

ou

```
var Code = document.body.querySelectorAll(".menu")[1].outerHTML;
```

---

Se quiser pegar o HTML interno do elemento:

```
var Code = document.body.querySelector(".menu").innerHTML;
```

ou

```
var Code = document.body.querySelectorAll(".menu")[1].innerHTML;
```

> Lembrando que o índice `[1]` é um exemplo que se refere ao segundo elemento com a
>   classe `.menu`, quando houverem mais de 1 elemento com a mesma classe.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer pegar um código html e atribui a uma variável chame ela por um id, classe, nome da tag ou algo assim:

```js
var code = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]

console.log(code)
```

```html
<div class="menu">...</div>
```